# How can I add sound to a button in iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nssound

I would like to make a sound play when a button is pressed. Also, there is more than one sound. I am using Xcode 4.4.1 and Storyboard.

In the .h file

```
{
    IBOutlet UIButton *playSound;
}
```

Comment: Please show what you have currently; it's unlikely anyone is going to write a project for you.

Comment: I'm modifying your question's title to remove Xcode from it.  Xcode is merely the developer environment. What you really care about is that you want to do this under iOS.

Comment: Actually, it's Cocoa-Touch that's important, as it's the API he will use inside iOS. :)

Comment: {

    IBOutlet UIButton *playSound;
}
in the.h file

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I thought it would be fun to write this type example so I wrote it. It demonstrates how to play different random sound when button is pressed:

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressedWithSound:(id)sender {

    int randomSoundNumber = arc4random() % 4; //random number from 0 to 3

    NSLog(@"random sound number = %i", randomSoundNumber);

    NSString *effectTitle;

    switch (randomSoundNumber) {
        case 0:
            effectTitle = @"sound1";
            break;
        case 1:
            effectTitle = @"sound2";
            break;
        case 2:
            effectTitle = @"sound3";
            break;
        case 3:
            effectTitle = @"sound4";
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    SystemSoundID soundID;

    NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:effectTitle ofType:@"caf"];
    NSURL *soundUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath];

    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID ((CFURLRef)soundUrl, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);  
}
```

**Explanation:**

- Add four sounds in Your project: *sound1.caf*, *sound2.caf*, *sound3.caf* and *sound4.caf*.
- Import AudioToolbox framework to Your project. And include in .h `#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>`.
- Don't forget to connect Your button to *buttonPressedWithSound* via `IBAction`.

Comment: @KyleGreenlaw You're getting this because You didn't included AudioToolbox framework to project (take a look at explanation at the bottom).

Comment: Can i use a mp3 file and not a caf file?

Comment: Sure, just change type to mp3 like this: `NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:effectTitle ofType:@"mp3"];`

Comment: @KyleGreenlaw I created project for you for more clarity so take a look at it http://www8.zippyshare.com/v/70589015/file.html.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the sound effects?

Comment: @JustinBoo thanks. It's just that I have been looking to find an appropriate button press sound effect, but I can't seem to find the right one. That's why I asked for the source. I don't think my users would like the car tag sounds from soundbible when they press a button.

Comment: @JustinBoo "mp3" didn't work for me in this case, I had to convert sound to .caf

Answer (score 1):

I have found this way, and it works for me

```
SystemSoundID soundID;
NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:ClickSoundFile ofType:FileTypemp3];
NSURL *soundUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID ((__bridge CFURLRef)soundUrl, &soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
```

*Note

ClickSoundFile : Sound file name
   FileTypemp3 : file type mp3