# How to add sound effects to an Xcode project?

Tags: ios, xcode, resources

This is my code right now. 
I am trying to add sound effects when a button is pressed.

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

- (void)threeBombExplosion
{
    NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"3Explosions" ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSURL *threeExplosionsURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath];
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(CFBridgingRetain(threeExplosionsURL),&_threeExplosionsID);

}
```

and I am calling this on the function I want it to be executed (UIButton Action).

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(_threeExplosionsID);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add sound to a button in iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11888059/how-can-i-add-sound-to-a-button-in-ios)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, thats not how you should be calling your mp3 file, you should be using the av audio player object.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"3Explosions" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSURL *soundUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
// Create audio player object and initialize with URL to sound
self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundUrl error:nil];
```

**Make sure you have strong reference to it, otherwise it might get removed in memory**

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
```

I would check that the method is being called when the button is being pressed. 
If you have a touchupinside action, then your method will be:

```
-(IBAction)buttonPressed {
    [self threeBombExplosion];
}
```

If that is not working, you should check that the resource is being added to your project, in Xcode you need to make sure you have added it.

[image]

In my project i created a subfolder called resources and then an additional one called sounds and placed it neatly in there.

Comment: Not sure that "you should be using the AV Audio Player", Audio Services system sounds work very well for simple purposes like this one.

Comment: The sounds he is trying to play are not system sounds, they are game sounds.